# Is the loading of ESModule asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bun

I read the documentation of bun two days ago. I am having a hard time understanding this:

> "[The biggest difference between CommonJS and ES Modules is that CommonJS modules are synchronous, while ES Modules are asynchronous.](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/modules) ".

I googled it and found out many people also mentioned this, but no one explained it. Here's some reference:

- [How to dynamically load ESM in CJS](https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-dynamically-load-an-esm-module-in-cjs/#:%7E:text=The%20main%20distinction%20between%20ESM%20and%20CJS%20is%20the%20loading%20of%20modules.%20ESM%20loads%20asynchronous%20and%20CJS%20loads%20synchronous.%20There%20are%20limitations%20in%20interoperability%2C%20while%20ESM%20can%20import%20CJS%2C%20CJS%20cannot%20require%20ESM%2C%20because%20it%20would%20break%20the%20synchronous%20constraint.)
- [CommonJS (cjs) and Modules (esm): Import compatibility](https://adamcoster.com/blog/commonjs-and-esm-importexport-compatibility-examples#:%7E:text=CommonJS%20imports%20are,level%20await)
- [Interoperability with CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs:%7E:text=An%20import%20statement%20can%20reference%20an%20ES%20module%20or%20a%20CommonJS%20module.%20import%20statements%20are%20permitted%20only%20in%20ES%20modules%2C%20but%20dynamic%20import()%20expressions%20are%20supported%20in%20CommonJS%20for%20loading%20ES%20modules.)

From my point, the loading of ES modules are synchronous with the static import. For example:

```js
// exporter.mjs
console.log("exporter");
```

```js
// importer.mjs
import "exporter.mjs"
console.log("importer");
```

Using this command `node importer.mjs`. Well, if the loading of `exporter.js` is asynchronous, the output would be "importer" printing first and "exporter" following. While the result is "exporter" printing first and "importer" following.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDGe8.png)

This proved that the loading of ES modules are synchronous with the static import, in which case we could import ES modules in CommonJS modules. While the article I mentioned above all say "we can't import ES modules in CommonJS modules, we have to use [the dynamic import function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)" , so did the documentation of nodejs. However, we could import ES modules in CommonJS modules in Bun. This is an example:

```js
// exporter.mjs
export let number = 10;
```

```js
// importer.cjs
const { number } = require("./exporter.mjs");

console.log(number);
```

Using this command `bun importer.cjs`. We can get the output like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfIa3.png)

I am really confused.

Comment: Think in terms of multiple imports. You can have 20 imports, and in Node, as legacy CJS modules, those will all load one by one, in order. In modern JS, as ESM, all 20 will load concurrently without any guarantee about what order they actually load in (which is fine, bcause that's not something you should need to rely on anyway).

Comment: If the module is loading asynchronously, why node print the exporter first?

Comment: Because that's not module related. ESM imports all happen at the same time, and only _after_ all imports have resolved does the rest of your script run. This isn't the same "asynchronous" as async/await, it's about how the JS engine performs module resolution, which it does _before_ code gets executed, per script. So if you start with 20 imports, all of those will be handled (including running code in those modules) without any guarantee about "which happens first",  all at the "same time", and only after all of them have been handled will your own code get run.

Comment: Thank you for your asking, any references for this? I appreciate it.

Comment: "*if the loading of exporter.js is asynchronous, the output would be "importer" printing first and "exporter" following*" - no. So you have not proven anything.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans They may *load* concurrently, but ESM still has deterministic evaluation order for declared imports. Only if you fire off multiple dynamic imports, there is a race

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea that "CommonJS modules are synchronous and ES Modules are asynchronous" by itself might be a bit of an over-simplification which causes this confusion. Let's add some context.

## How do ES Modules work?

ES Modules go through the following steps:

1. **Load**: Asynchronously loads dependencies.

   From the spec:

   > Prepares the module for linking by recursively loading all its dependencies, and returns a promise.
2. **Link**: Connects module exports with imports in memory.

   From the spec:

   > Prepare the module for evaluation by transitively resolving all module dependencies and creating a Module Environment Record.
   >
   > LoadRequestedModules must have completed successfully prior to invoking this method.
3. **Evaluate (and execute)**: Run the code.

   From the spec:

   > Returns a promise for the evaluation of this module and its dependencies, resolving on successful evaluation or if it has already been evaluated successfully, and rejecting for an evaluation error or if it has already been evaluated unsuccessfully. If the promise is rejected, hosts are expected to handle the promise rejection and rethrow the evaluation error.
   >
   > Link must have completed successfully prior to invoking this method.

As you can see from the quotes from the [JavaScript/ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-abstract-methods-of-module-records), various steps are performed asynchronously however steps depend on each other. In practice, this means dependencies will be evaluated and executed before the dependent, which gives the impression that ES modules are synchronous.

## How do CommonJS modules work?

CommonJS is different because it uses a function (`require`) to import modules. This means, dependencies are only known at runtime (when the code is executed). In other words, code is executed first then dependencies are loaded; as opposed to ES modules which loads dependencies first then executes the code. The synchronous nature of `require` comes in because when a `require` function is encountered, code after the function is not run until after the `require` function has loaded and executed the code within the dependency.

## A practical comparison

This difference in the order of loading vs execution becomes apparent in a case like this (assuming an entry point of `a.js`):

|  | CommonJS | ES Modules |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a.js | ``` const { b } = require("./b"); console.log(b); exports.a = "a"; ``` | ``` import { b } from "./b"; console.log(b); export const a = "a"; ``` |
| b.js | ``` const { a } = require("./a"); setTimeout(() => { console.log(a); }, 0); exports.b = "b"; ``` | ``` import { a } from "./a"; setTimeout(() => { console.log(a); }, 0); export const b = "b"; ``` |
| **Logs** | ``` b undefined ``` | ``` b a ``` |

In the CommonJS case, `a.js` requires `b.js`. As `require` is synchronous, it blocks the export of `a`. As a result, `a` is undefined in `b.js`.

In the ES Module case, while `a.js` also requires `b.js`, the link between the `a` export in `a.js` and import in `b.js` is set up before code is executed. As module evaluation and execution occurs asynchronously, `a` is exported before the `setTimeout`'s callback execution meaning `a` will have its value initialised to `"a"`. Why this happens is because Promises are scheduled in the microtask queue while timers are scheduled in the macrotask queue; and microtasks are executed before macrotasks. This itself is a whole topic that already has answers elsewhere on the internet. I'll include something in the further reading below.

## Further reading

- For all the low-level details: [ECMAScript Specification: Modules](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-modules)
- For an easier to understand dive into ES Modules: [ES Modules: A cartoon deep-dive](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)
- Understanding why Promises execute before timers and what on earth micro/macro-tasks are (and more): [JavaScript.info: Event Loop](https://javascript.info/event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

`import * as foo from './foo'` being asynchronous means it's a complete equivalent of
`const foo = await import('./foo')`
which only makes a difference if './foo' has a *top level await*

As the doc says,

> The only exception to this rule is top-level await. You can't require() a file that uses top-level await, since the require() function is inherently synchronous

Comment: No, this is not a complete equivalent; in particular if you are doing anything in the lines above that statement. Also there are some subtleties wrt linking and aliases, where the namespace is already usable while the *foo* module is being evaluated, while the `const` is not.