# Is module system resolution in Python synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: python

In JavaScript world there are two types of module systems - CommonJS and ES modules. They use different resolution systems - CommonJS is synchronous and ES modules is asynchronous.

Based on this quote from the "Learning Python" book it seems that the module system is synchronous:

> To satisfy such goals, import (and, as you’ll see later, from)
> statements execute and load other files on request. More formally, in
> Python, cross-file module linking is not resolved until **such import
> statements are executed at runtime**; their net effect is to assign
> module names—simple variables like b—to loaded module objects. In
> fact, the module name used in an import statement serves two purposes:
> it identifies the external file to be loaded, but it also becomes a
> variable assigned to the loaded module.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: What does "synchronous" and "asynchronous" mean here? What's written in the quote is correct.

Comment: Nothing in Python is asynchronous by default. Asynchronous code is very explicit about being asynchronous. This is unlike Javascript, which is very asynchronous by design. It doesn't need to be explicitly clarified in Python. Everything is synchronous unless it very explicitly isn't.

Comment: @mkrieger1 asynchronous means that the dependency graph is resolved and linked before the module code starts executing, for example see the comparison in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77117929/2545680). Async resolution also means that dependencies will be evaluated and executed before the dependent module.

Comment: @deceze, this different about module resolution isn't really related to runtime execution of code (sync or async), it's whether the module deps are resolved and linked before the module code execution starts, sort of before the "runtime" phase

Comment: Then it's synchronous.

Comment: As the documentation says: **import statements are executed at runtime**, if and when they're encountered. They're no different from other code like function calls and such.

Comment: @mkrieger1, thanks, could you also confirt that the `import` statement in a Python module **can't** be a non top-level statement? for example, it **can't** be put into the body of a function that is executed at some point later in time? 

I'm asking this b/c in JS the CommonJS system allows non top level imports, while ES Modules require all import statements at the top level because of the async nature of module resolution

Comment: You can easily confirm that this is not true yourself: define a function which contains an `import` statement and call the function. There will be no error.

Comment: @mkrieger1, got it, it seems then using `import` as top level is simply a recommendation, otherwise the module resolution seems to behave similar to synchronous CommonJS, for example, with this code in `main.py`: 
`def f(): import a 
  print(a.version)
  print('from main')
  f()`

and this in `a.py`: 
`print('from a')
 version = 'v3'`. 

I get the following output: `from main`, `from a` and then `v3`. Which means Python executes `main.py`, encounters `import a`, and executes `a.py`.

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to keep comparing Python to JS. A Python `import` statement imports a module when it is encountered (while caching the import so as not to re-import already loaded modules) and makes the imported names available in the scope where the statement is. Period.